# specific information from google search result

Tags: vba, excel

I use the following code to collect the first URL from a Google search. Is there a way to edit the code so that it picks up just the the text located right after the green URL in the Google search results?

Each search result contains 4 lines of information:

```
header
URL in green
text1
text2
```

I want to collect the single line of text which is shown after the green URL.

Is this possible?

```
Sub XMLHTTP()

Dim url As String, lastRow As Long
Dim XMLHTTP As Object, html As Object, objResultDiv As Object, objH3 As Object, link As Object
Dim start_time As Date
Dim end_time As Date

lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Dim cookie As String
Dim result_cookie As String

start_time = Time
Debug.Print "start_time:" & start_time
On Error Resume Next
For i = 2 To lastRow

    url = "https://www.google.co.in/search?q=" & Cells(i, 1) & "&rnd=" & WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 10000)

    Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")
    XMLHTTP.Open "GET", url, False
    XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
    XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"
    XMLHTTP.send

        Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    html.body.innerHTML = XMLHTTP.ResponseText
    Set objResultDiv = html.getelementbyid("rso")
    Set objH3 = objResultDiv.getelementsbytagname("H3")(0)
    Set link = objH3.getelementsbytagname("a")(0)


    str_text = Replace(link.innerHTML, "<EM>", "")
    str_text = Replace(str_text, "</EM>", "")

    Cells(i, 2) = str_text
    Cells(i, 3) = link.href
    DoEvents
Next

end_time = Time
Debug.Print "end_time:" & end_time

Debug.Print "done" & "Time taken : " & DateDiff("n", start_time, end_time)
MsgBox "done" & "Time taken : " & DateDiff("n", start_time, end_time)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like the text is within a `<span class="st">`, so this should do the trick:

```
Dim HTML
Set HTML = CreateObject("htmlfile")
HTML.body.innerHTML = XMLHTTP.ResponseText

Dim e
For Each e In HTML.getElementsByTagName("span")
    If e.className = "st" Then
        Debug.Print e.innerText
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

---

**Edit**: Showing complete script:

```
Dim XMLHTTP
Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")
XMLHTTP.Open "GET", "https://www.google.co.in/search?q=test", False
XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"
XMLHTTP.send

Dim HTML
Set HTML = CreateObject("htmlfile")
HTML.body.innerHTML = XMLHTTP.ResponseText

Dim e
For Each e In HTML.getElementsByTagName("span")
    If e.className = "st" Then
        Debug.Print e.innerText
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Output

```
Test your Internet connection bandwidth to locations around the world with this interactive broadband speed test from Ookla.
```

Comment: is it working for you, nothing happens when i run the code

Comment: Yes. It did for me. I copied it directly from a working script.

Comment: strange. its not working in here, could  you please share the code you used.

Comment: I've edited the answer to show the entire script I used.